# What is the total number of handshakes if six people shake each others hand exactly once?

Tags: combinatorics

Six people enter a room and introduce themselves to each other . Everyone everyone shake everyones hand exactly once. What is the total number of handshakes?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include any work you have done on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: It's problem of combinatorics.

Notice, 
$$\text{total no. of hand shakes}=\text{number of ways of selecting two (pair) out of six people}$$  $$=\binom{6}{2}=\frac{6!}{(6-2)!2!}=\frac{6!}{4!2!}=\frac{6\times 5\times 4!}{4!2!}=\frac{30}{2}=15$$